# Styled component input loses focus onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

When using an html input with [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/) and saving the value to react state with onChange, the component appears to be re-rendering on every state change and causing the input to lose focus. Is there any way to prevent the input from losing focus? Why is this occurring? [Here is an example](https://codepen.io/jjbskir/pen/VowBjr).

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = { val: "" };

  render() {
    const Input = styled.input`
      border-radius: 6px;
    `;

    return (
      <Input
        value={this.state.val}
        onChange={e => this.setState({ val: e.target.value })}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `styled.input` creates a new legit react component. It should be defined outside `MyComponent`. If you intend to define styles exclusively for a particular `input` without defining a separate component, consider using [css prop](https://medium.com/styled-components/announcing-native-support-for-the-css-prop-in-styled-components-245ca5252feb).

Answer (score 18):

On every render, you generate a new `Input` therefore loss of focus.

Decouple the style from the component:

```js
const Input = styled.input`
  border-radius: 6px;
`;

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = { val: "" };

  render() {
    return (
      <Input
        value={this.state.val}
        onChange={e => this.setState({ val: e.target.value })}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Dennis Vash said on every render the component is compiled. Re-compiling the Styled-CSS with is link to the component.
Similarly if you used styled components in function. Copy-paste it outside the function so that the variable is created only once

```
    const CustomInput = styled.input`
       border:none;
       border-radius:0px;
       padding:2px 11px;
       border-bottom:1px solid #ced4da;
       &:focus {
         outline: none;
         border-color:#ced4da;
       }
   `;

   function myFun(props){
         const [value, setvalue] = useState('')
         return (
             <CustomInput 
                value={value}
                onChange={(e)=>setvalue(e.target.value)}
             />
         )
   }
```

Comment: hi, i'm having the exact same issue, but I have already placed my styled component outside of my main component. In fact it's in a different folder. Any idea why this is occurring?

Comment: This worked for me. Not sure about yours, will need to check your code to trace it. 
If you know about memo you can give it try! Ref: -> https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo. Simply wrap the styled component in memo i.e memo(styled.input` ....`);

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you've defined `Input` within the `render()` method. Every time the state gets updated, the `render()` method will be called and `Input` will be redefined and handled as if it was a completely new component (a html `<input/>` without focus in this case). If you move the definition of `Input` out of the component, it will work as intended. Also the fragment you've used (`</>`) in the return of the `render()` method is kind of pointless.

```
const Input = styled.input`
  border-radius: 6px;
`;

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = { val: '' };

  render(){
    return(
      <Input
        value={this.state.val}
        onChange={e => this.setState({ val: e.target.value })}
      />
    );
  }
}
```