# How to keep focus on styled-component input component on input value change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I'm rendering a `Field` component which uses styled components to build an `input` field. The issue I'm running into is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57096907/styled-component-input-loses-focus-onchange). I'm not defining the `Field` component in the `App` component but I'm still facing the same issue where I lose input on each input value change. It seems that a new `Field` component is being rendered but without focus. Is there a way for me to prevent a new `Field` component from being rendered or will I have to set the focus on each input change somehow and if I do is this good practice or something I should avoid due to performance or other issues? I created a [github repo here](https://github.com/cbryant24/react-form) if more details or context is needed. [Codesandbox with example of issue here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-styled-component-issue-fd3n0)

```
const App = () => {
  const [emailVal, setEmailVal] = useState("");
  const [passwordVal, setPasswordVal] = useState("");

  const handleChange = e => {
    if (e.target.name === "email") {
      setEmailVal(e.target.value);
      return;
    }

    setPasswordVal(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <Box as="form">
      <Field
        data={{
          name: "email",
          type: "text",
          placeholder: "enter email",
          label: "email"
        }}
        errors={[]}
        value={emailVal}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <Field
        data={{
          name: "password",
          type: "password",
          placeholder: "enter password",
          label: "email"
        }}
        errors={[]}
        value={passwordVal}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </Box>
  );
};
```

```
const Field = ({ data: { name, type, placeholder, label }, value, onChange }) => {

  return (
    <Box>
      <Box
        value={value}
        onChange={onChange}
        as='input'
        name={name}
        placeholder={placeholder}
      />
    </Box>
  );
};
```

Comment: Your complete and reproducible, but not minimal:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Try to scale your example down to the smallest example you can create that will reproduce your problem. You might even find the source of the issue just by doing this.

I tried to read your code but it is so unnecessarily convoluted that I had to give up.

Comment: Thanks @RicardoLopes I scaled down the code, hopefully it is more readable. After scaling it down the issue still persists though.

Comment: Much better, but I'm still confused what you're trying to achieve by all this. From what I can tell, the problem resides in `Box.js`, specifically in your `Base` component. You can see that replacing the line `const Box = styled(cleanElement(Base))(` with `const Box = styled.div` makes the problem go away. What exactly are you trying to achieve that requires this `Base` element? Seems like `filterprops` and `cleanElement` do the same thing?

Comment: And just to clarify, it's normal that you are losing focus because you are recreating the whole component every time by going through this `Base` element.

Comment: I was running into an issue where some props were ending up on the element. But you're right though that is what is causing the issue. Making that change solves the issue. Thanks!